# Mod Rewrite generating 500 internal error on page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some reason my .HTACCESS file won't re-write my users page, even though I'm sure the code to re-write it is correct.

I want to turn

```
http://www.tfreeb.com/user/user?user=duenna
```

Into

```
http://www.tfreeb.com/user/duenna
```

And this is my HTACCESS file, could it be that something else is conflicting with it?

The re-write rule for the user page is right at the bottom.

```
Options -Indexes

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log

php_value error_reporting 32767


ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.tfreeb.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.tfreeb.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^213\.143\.20\.122
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.tfreeb.com/$1 [R=301,L]



RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /user/user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.tfreeb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Try with that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /user/user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

No need to use multiple times `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Oh my god, that actually worked. Can you explain why if you don't mind?

Comment: You must place the rule about the user, before the other which redirect all to .php. And I test before if file or directory exist (without redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the .htaccess is being read?

I'd try to make a basic redirect to some page, p.e. google.com if this doesn't work you should ask to the web server admin to give you the AllowOverride = all directive for the directory.

p.e.

```
<directory /var/www/mysite>
    AllowOverride = all
</directory>
```

Comment: Its definitely working because other re-write rules are working, its just he last one that doesnt

Comment: I think that you have a '/' missing in 
RewriteRule ^**bold**/**bold**user/([^/]*)$ /user/user.php?user=$1 [L]

Shoud be:

Comment: Sorry for the previous one, I can't edit it any more. ..... I think that you have a '/' missing between '^' and 'user' 
RewriteRule ^/user/([^/]*)$ /user/user.php?user=$1 [L]